# TFS 2015 Team Build failing for setup projects - An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, devenv

We're using Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2015. We have a separate build server on which we've deployed a build agent, VS 2015 and the MS extension for installer projects (found here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

Our solution includes a number of setup projects. However, the team build fails when trying to build these projects. The error is

> An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'

There are a few results returned searching for a solution to this problem (including several pages on Stack Overflow) and they pretty much all boil down to the one suggestion of adding or setting a value of 0 for EnableOutOfProcBuild to the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild

We followed this advice and, while it allowed us to build the setup projects from a command line on the build machine, it hasn't helped with the team build. Note, we've tried adding the registry setting in various places but none have helped. Also note, we're running the build agent service under an administrator account.

The build step for each setup project is a Command Line with

- tool : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv"
- arguments: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(system.teamProject)\Raven.sln
  /build    "Release" /project

  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(system.teamProject)\src...\ourproj.vdproj
  /projectConfig "Release"

(note paths and names anonymised) which comes out as expected in the build logs and copying the log command line and executing in a command prompt on the build server does indeed work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any other error messages, could you please post all of them here

Comment: There are no other errors in the logs

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: xxx (BL\xxx\xxx), Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>  xxx -> C:\Agent\agent\_work\9c81b20c\yyy\xxx\bin\Release\xxx.exe
Starting pre-build validation for project 'xxx' ------ 
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
Pre-build validation for project 'xxx' completed ------
2>------ Build started: Project: xxx, Configuration: Release ------
Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Try to change system.debug variable to true and queue build, then check whether there are detail errors.

Comment: No more detailed errors - still just the same output for the deploy project.

Comment: @Stephen did you solved the problem ? i have the same issue in my projects

Comment: Hey Leon. Still haven't managed to solve this. Installed update 4 of TFS 2015 and reconfigured the agent in hopes that would work, but it didn't. Don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Jenkins CI Tool
The below steps will resolve the issue.

```
[![1.Open Service.msc as administrator
2.go to service for me Jenkins, for you May TFS
3.Right-click and select properties
4.Click on log On tab
5.Select This account and put user and password of your user. Make sure user is available by using Browse.
6.Click Apply and Ok.
7.Restart the service.][1]][1]
```

It may resolve your issues.

[image: Change Ci tool service login]

Comment: I can confirm that that solves my problem. Service displayed name of agent: `VSTS Agent ([AGENT NAME])`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, refer to [this blog](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build), you need to set 0 to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild\EnableOutOfProcBuild`.

Then I suggest that before you do that in TFS, you'll have to get it working from the command line first on TFS build agent server, otherwise the build will never work in TFS.

And in the **Command Line** step, I found that something you need to change:

- tool : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"
- arguments: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)..\Raven.sln /build "Release" /project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)...\src...\ourproj.vdproj /projectConfig "Release".

The solution path and project path you should make sure it is correct and it could be found on build agent server. $(Build.SourcesDirectory) may represents 'C:\Agent_work\1\s'.

Make sure you're calling the correct **devenv.com** to build the solution.

Comment: As I said above, we've done all of that. We followed that blog and posts on various sites from StackOverflow and Microsoft. We have made the suggested registry change and we have checked that we can build from a command line - in fact, as I pointed out above, we actually went so far as to copy the exact command line that was produced in the TFS build logs and executed it without change in a Command prompt on the build server and it did indeed build the deploy project. We had done all of this and still the scripted build didn't work, which is why I posted the question on here.

Comment: @Did this project created in lower version of Visual Studio and upgrade to VS 2015? And do you have any other build agent, configure a new build agent and try again?

Comment: This project was indeed upgraded from a VS2010 version. Is there something specific we need to do as a result? Haven't been able to deploy a different build agent yet, will do that as soon as we get time.

Answer (score 1):

Is your EnableOutOfProcBuild 64-bit or 32-bit DWORD? My Visual Studio 2015 is 32-bit and I needed to set this registry key to 32-bit to fix the build error. I first set the key to 64-bit DWORD and it did not fix the build error 8000000A. I use nant version 0.92 to run build script.

I don't use 64-bit VS 2015. If you have 64-bit VS 2015, you may need to set the EnableOutOfProcBuild to 64-bit DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved that by following steps:

1)  Check the Build option for setup project in Solution Property Pages window and save the solution.

2) Create or edit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\MSBuild\EnableOutOfProcBuild to have a DWORD of 0. I have VS 2013 installed, so i looked inside "12.0_Config"

3) Try again with devenv command and got the success response

"========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped =========="

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you run VSTS/TFS/Azure DevOps Private agent as a windows service, right click the service and click on the log on tab, then re-login with administrator or your user account. then restart the service. It will fix this issue.